# Formulario para arquivo HTML Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Olá! Quero uma ajuda aqui: Quero que quando uma pessoa escreva algo num formulário HTML, com o `node.js`, eu possa salvar essas informações em um arquivo de texto com o createFile. Não sei muito de javascript, ajudem por favor :/

Comment: Estás a usar o `expressjs`?

Comment: Não, mas se não existir outra maneira posso inserir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, a resposta em inglês está em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js
Basicamente, você precisará da lib fs.
Seguindo o codigo abaixo, voce consegue criar o arquivo, basta receber a informação do HTML no server node e passar ao segundo parâmetro.

```
// -------------------------

var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/pasta/test", "Criando novo arquivo!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("o arquivo foi gravado!");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, dividindo por partes tens de:

- enviar os dados para o servidor
- interpretar os dados (para evitar escrever só um dump do body)
- gravar num ficheiro

Nota que quando te referes à função [`createFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) estás a falar de *.NET* e não de Node.js. Mas vou assumir que queres algo semelhante em Node.js

#### Enviar os dados para o servidor:

Esta parte é feita no lado do cliente. Na sua maneira mais simples é só com HTML mas há outras maneiras, usando ajax. Mas na versão mais simples tens um formulário tipo este:

```html
    <form action="/dados-formulario" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="username">
          <input type="password" name="password">
          <input type="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
```

#### Interpretar os dados no servidor:

Na verdade, sugiro usares o [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) do `express` para isso e juntares como middleware:

```js
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

O que esse plugin/middleware faz é converter o texto que o servidor recebe e separar tudo certinho para dar para trabalhar no Node. Tudo o que for passado pelo formulário estará no `req.body` que com o middleware do `body-parser` é um objeto com chaves valor de cada `input`, `select` etc que tenhas na `<form>`. O `name` do elemento é a chave da propriedade de `req.body`.

#### Gravar num ficheiro:

Sugiro que graves isso num JSON. A função a usar é [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback), vou dar exemplo da versão assíncrona. O [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) é nativo do Node.js mas tem de ser adicionado no código.

```js
    app.post('/dados-formulario', function(req, res){
        var conteudo = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile('nome-do-ficheiro.txt', conteudo, 'utf8', function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          // correr código aqui depois do ficheiro estar gravado
        });
    });
```